# pjsip sip header configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, pjsip

I am using Sip in my ios projects and siphon classes on top of **pjsip sdk** .

I have no problem with **basic configuration** and therefore I need to add some custom data to my sip header whenever I make a sip call.

I have the following header format

> pjsua_core.c  .  TX 1123 bytes   Request msg INVITE/cseq=31730 (tdta0x92aa400) to   UDP   xxxxx:   5060:
>
> INVITE sip:xxx9@xxxxxx SIP/2.0
>
> Via: SIP/2.0/UDP xxxxx:xxx;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjt.fUN05fzpwxbm5zJvjoGSA.bnLvoAHl
>
> Max-Forwards: 70
>
> From: sip:xxxx@xxxxx;tag=d1Ww0T4iQNqygphKlqLQ.iNcYx-Cdsb2
>
> To: sip:xxxx@xxxxxxxx
>
> Contact:
>
> Call-ID: a3zCaQtWPsnKrlbyYtLwwhUQgxnLs8hv
>
> CSeq: 31730 INVITE
>
> Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
>
> Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
>
> Session-Expires: 1800
>
> Min-SE: 90
>
> User-Agent: Siphon PjSip v2.0.1svn/arm-apple-darwin9
>
> ;sdsd: BLABLABLA
>
> Content-Type: application/sdp
>
> Content-Length:   448
>
> v=0
>
> o=- 3563345387 3563345387 IN IP4 192.168.1.3
>
> s=pjmedia
>
> b=AS:84
>
> t=0 0
>
> a=X-nat:0
>
> m=audio 40000 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 96
>
> c=IN IP4 192.168.1.3
>
> b=TIAS:64000
>
> a=rtcp:40001 IN IP4 192.168.1.3
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000
>
> a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000
>
> a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000
>
> a=fmtp:104 mode=30
>
> a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000
>
> a=fmtp:96 0-15

--end msg--

I want to change the following two lines

> From: sip:xxxx@xxxxx;tag=d1Ww0T4iQNqygphKlqLQ.iNcYx-Cdsb2
>
> To: sip:xxxx@xxxxxxxx

to look like this

> From: sip:xxxx@xxxxx;tag=d1Ww0T4iQNqygphKlqLQ.iNcYx-Cdsb2;textid=1 ;texfrom=2;textto=4
>
> To: sip:xxxx@xxxxxxxx

just like that.

Kindly, provide some clarity.

Comment: I an using PJSIP. I need to fetch dialed number through dialer pad. This one
To: sip:+791595XXXXX@call.com

Answer (score 0):

pjsip uses `pjsua_call_make_call` API to make a call. Inside this it creates a dialog with a call to `pjsip_dlg_create_uac`. You can pass your custom headers to this API. More information [here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSIP__DIALOG.htm#ga6643135a8dbee20a156c1046fda27e03)